Smart vapor retarder for retrofit preferrably sprayon/roll on
Does any one know if there are Smart vapor retarders for Retrofit purposes? Im needing to install from the outside of the house as the interior walls cant come down and the outside is needing to be replaced.  the interior is the panel board walls like from the 80's.  6" studs with worn out fiberglass insulation that has to go. i currently have NO barriers what so ever due to how the place was constructed. I am hoping to get a spray/roll on retarder to go on the panel boards and studs  then add rock wull to the cavity and insulated zip for the outside since there was no sheathing and cement board for the external cover.
I have been able to source all the others but have not found any smart barrier/retarder for retrofits.
